# Where should a default setting field be?

Tags: database-design, database-theory

I am creating a database to track occurrences of incidents on buses based on an existing system. Currently the drivers can set a default bus number, which is used to pre-populate the bus number on the incident form. Where they can change that then, if they are driving another bus. This is a selection made by the driver. Not a bus assigned to them, per say. I was going to put this field in the staff table, not the bus table. However, someone said I should not, that I should put it in the bus table. I guess it would technically work either way, but I don't feel like the field belongs to the bus - it belongs to the staff member. Am I overthinking this?

Comment: No, you are right. It's a selection made by a driver. So it belongs to the `stuff` table or a new table with 1-1 relationship with the stuff table. It couldn't on the `bus` table as a bus could be selected (I guess) as default by more than one drivers.

Comment: Thank you! Since you said it that way, that made me think I may have misunderstood them. Perhaps they were recommending a supporting table, rather than further "cluttering" the main table. I'll consider that more. I was just second-guessing myself. Thanks again!

Comment: As an aside, if it is an attribute of the driver entity (which it sounds like it is) then adding it to the driver table is not "cluttering".